# Instant chat for self-hosting

Tags: gratis, linux, chat, web-server

I am looking for a software that

- allows to create chat rooms instantly
- once created, it needs just a URL to log in, no password
- chat sessions are deleted automatically after a defined period of inactivity
- allows images in chat messages
- is free
- runs on Linux (Ubuntu)

The closest I know to what I'm looking for is [stinto.net](http://stinto.net). But that's just free and not available for download. It just needs 2 clicks: create a chat and start chatting. Anyone else knowing the URL can join.